# Diff two XML doc in Ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby, diff

What's the easiest way to see the difference between two xml files using?

I looked into Hpricot and Nokogiri but couldn't find any good comparison methods. I've also looked into unix tools like [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/), but would rather use something in ruby.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question.  Diffing trees and diffing sequences are different (though abstractly related) problems.

Answer (score 1):

What about [diff.rb](http://users.cybercity.dk/~dsl8950/ruby/diff.html) ?
You export your two xml documents to arrays and get the diff with that library.

Comment: the link is no longer working!

Answer (score 1):

Try the [equivalent-xml gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/equivalent-xml).  It can tell you if two XML documents are semantically equivalent

Answer (score 0):

I found that was easier to use the Java library [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net) than any native solution

```
require 'java'
require '/usr/share/java/xmlunit.jar'
java_import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff

puts Diff.new("<a></a>", "<a/>").similar
puts Diff.new("<a/>", "<b/>").similar
```

Of course, this means you have to use JRuby instead of CRuby, but that wasn't a significant obstacle in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to regularize your xml by round tripping it through xml-simple, and then doing an array diff on the lines of the output:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'xmlsimple'
require 'diff'

def regularize(xml)
  XmlSimple.xml_out(XmlSimple.xml_in(xml))
end

def diff_xml(a,b)
  Diff.new(regularize(a).split("\n"), regularize(b).split("\n"))
end

puts diff_xml("<doc><a/></doc>", "<doc><a></a></doc>").diffs.empty?
puts diff_xml("<doc><a/></doc>", "<doc><b/></doc>").diffs.empty?
```