# Is there a ruby gem that does diff between HTML documents?

Tags: ruby, version-control, rubygems, merge, diff

Doing a diff of two different html documents turns out to be an entirely different problem than simply doing a diff of plain text. For example, if I do a naive LCS diff between:

```
Google</p>
```

and

```
Google</a></p>
```

---

the diff result is NOT:

```
</a>
```

but

```
/a></
```

---

I've tried most gems out there that claim to be html diff but all of them seem to be just implementing text based LCS diff. Is there any gem that does a diff while taking html tags into account?

Comment: I don't know of any, but that doesn't mean that they don't exist. It would be interesting to create such a gem, using Nokogiri to generate comparable element trees and do a tree-based diff. Try searching the official gem repo at http://rubygems.org

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diff two XML doc in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558613/diff-two-xml-doc-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Samy diffy](https://github.com/samg/diffy) or [rubygems html-diff](https://rubygems.org/gems/html-diff)

Comment: Both of these only support diffing plain text and outputting HTML diffs, not diffing HTML and outputting HTML.

Comment: @ruxton did you end up finding what you were looking for?

Comment: @Richardsondx I don't recall what, but I do recall it being the most annoying part of the system I was working on.

Comment: @Ruxton not true anymore, `Diffy` works well with html!

Answer (score -2):

After much searching for a gem to do this for me, I discovered that I can simply do a string compare between two parsed Nokogiri documents:

```
def should_match_html(html_text1, html_text2)
  dom1 = Nokogiri::HTML(html_text1)
  dom2 = Nokogiri::HTML(html_text2)
  dom1.to_s.should == dom2.to_s
end
```

Then you can simply add this in your spec:

```
should_match_html expected_html, actual_html
```

The best part is that the built-in rspec matcher will automatically provide you a line-by-line diff result of the mismatched lines.