# Caching a website in Ruby, then checking for changes later? "Diffing?"

Tags: ruby, caching, web

I have, what I thought, was a pretty simple problem that someone would have created a gem for, but I am having a hard time searching for the silver bullet.

1) I'd like take a URL
2) create an md5, or "snapshot" of the site contents
3) then at a later date, see if the site has changed.

Is downloading the site and diffing the files the best way to do that? is there a way to serialize or encapsulate the site in a data object some how?

Comment: May be this will help: [How to compare two HTML page contents efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097074/is-there-a-ruby-gem-that-does-diff-between-html-documents)

Comment: You mean like `wget -m`? That plus `git` could go a long way towards what you want here, and it'll do all sorts of fun stuff like show diffs for free.